# CFURLResourceIsReachable failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a Cocoa program with deployment target 10.7, using the latest (10.8) SDK, I run it on 10.7.5 with XCode 4.6.2. In it I work with NSURLs with no problem whatsoever, everything works fine. One method I use is the NSURL method:

```
[newURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&error]
```

with newURL a pointer to aNSURL. So far so good.

However, when I compile and run this, on a mac mini with Mountain Lion installed the following warning appears:

CFURLResourceIsReachable failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme

and some other things now go wrong as well, such as

```
[dict setObject:url forKey:[url path]],
```

with dict a NSMutableDictionary and url a NSURL, the url simply is not added anymore to the dict. Strange isn't it? Did I miss a change in how NSURLs work from OS X 10.7 to 10.8?

Apologies if this already has been discussed here (I could not find it), thanks for looking at this question,

Marijn

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: for instance: file://localhost/Applications/auxiliary%20tools/
(for /Applications/auxiliary tools)
mind you, cocoa generated this url, via 
contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:
(again this causes no issues whatsoever on my 10.7.5 config)

Comment: add file:/// in front of your path